# g(x)=x odd and even expansions

Tags: fourier-series, fourier, digital

I'm studying book about digital filter by Richard Hamming. And there is exercise to get odd and even expansion of g(x)=x where x is from 0 to $\pi$. I understood even expansion, but can't get into odd expansion:
$\pi$ - $2$*(${\rm sin} x$ +  $\frac{1}{2}$${\rm sin} 2x$ + $\frac{1}{3}$${\rm sin} 3x$...)

Can anybody explain odd expansion of this function g(x)=x?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Let me be more clear. The exersise is: show that g(x) = x has two expansions (0 < x < $\pi$)

$x$ =$\begin{cases}\pi - 2*(\sin(x)+\sin(2x)/2+\sin(3x)/3+...)
\\\pi/2 - 4/\pi*(\cos(x)+\cos(3x)/3^2+\cos(5x)/5^2+...)\end{cases}$

I merely understand cosine expansion, but I don't understand sine expansion...

Comment: Perhaps you can include what Richard Hamming means by odd and even expansion for the benefit of those readers who do not have access to the book?

Comment: According to book: to get cosine expansion you extend the function about origin as an even function g(x)=(-x); and for only sines as an odd function g(x)=-g(-x).

Comment: There is something wrong.  If the _odd_ expansion of $g(x) =\begin{cases}x,&0 \leq x \leq \pi,\\0,&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$ is the _odd_ function $g(x) =\begin{cases}x,& |x| \leq \pi,\\0,&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$, then its Fourier series cannot have a DC term: odd functions have a DC term $0$, not $\pi$ as you have it.  On the other hand, the _even_ function $p(x) =\begin{cases}|x|,&-\pi \leq x \leq \pi,\\0,&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$ does indeed have a DC term of $\pi$ **but** the coefficients of the $\sin$ functions are all $0$. Please check that you have copied things correctly

Comment: That is why I'm asking this question... I guess in order to make function odd, we extend it with $\pi$ - x (or x - $\pi$) on interval from -$\pi$ to 0. There is another excersice where g(x) = x needed to be expanded on [0,$\pi$) he notes that if you substract $\pi$ from x you get odd function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to find a representation in terms of sines and cosines for the function
$g(x)$ which has value $x$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$. We don't really care if this
representation does not work well outside the interval $[0,\pi]$, but 
inside the interval, the representation better work perfectly.  This seems
to be crying out for a Fourier series approach, and so that's what we will
use.  The standard approach begins with functions that are periodic with
period $2\pi$ and so let us extend the definition of $g(x)$ to cover
one period $[0,2\pi]$.

- If we *choose* $g(x)$ to have value $2\pi-x$ for
  $x \in [\pi, 2\pi]$, then, when repeated periodically,
  this extended $g(x)$ is an *even* function of $x$ with average value $\pi/2$.
  Furthermore, as is the case with all even functions, the sine terms all 
  have $0$ coefficients.  Thus, the Fourier series works out to 
  have only cosines in it, and the DC term is $\pi/2$.
- If we choose $g(x)$ to have value $x$ for $x \in [\pi, 2\pi]$, then
  when repeated periodically,
  this extended $g(x)$ is not an *odd* function of $x$, but nonetheless
  it is true that all the cosine terms in the Fourier series
  turn out to be $0$ *except* the DC term which has value $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dilip! Very clear! The last question: why extended $g(x)$ is not an odd function? I guess it is truly odd function... Nevertheless, thank you very very much.

Comment: @Sharov If $g(x) = x, 0 \leq x < 2\pi$ is extended _periodically_ with period $2\pi$, then for $-2\pi \leq x < 0$, the _extended_ $g(x)$ equals $2\pi+x$, having value $0$ when $x = -2\pi$ and approaching $2\pi$ as $x$ approaches $0$.  So, the extended $g(x)$ is not an odd function.  If you subtract off the DC value $\pi$ and shift the function to the right by $\pi$, then it _is_ an odd function, being given by $x$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$